# Can I replace the swivel elbow of a p trap with a straight pipe

Tags: plumbing, sink, p-trap

Can I replace the swivel part of a ptrap with a straight connection right into the drains of my two sink bowls? Basically like in the picture. The red line shows where the threaded swivel connection used to be. It would result in a slightly deeper ptrap which I need to be able to connect it to the drain pipe coming from the wall.

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here?  With that trap you need a compression fitting, no matter how deep the trap is.

Comment: I actually completely changed the approach. I ended up breaking into the wall and lowering the entry point. The end goal was to simply modify the ptrap so it would fit in the space I had.